# Powershell Select Expanded Property and Custom Expression

Tags: powershell

I want to get the content of the first value of a specific column using `Import-Csv` output as a table alongside the name of the file.

I can do:

```
$File = '\\webserver\Data_20190626.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $File -Delimiter ',' | select 'Effective Date' -First 1
```

Which gives me my expected output:

```
Effective Date
--------------
25-May-2019
```

What I want to see is:

```
Effective Date     FileName
--------------     ---------
25-May-2019        Data_20190626.csv
```

I have tried this:

```
$File = '\\webserver\Data_20190626.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $File -Delimiter ',' | select 'Effective Date', @{N='FileName';E={$_.Name}} -First 1
```

Which resulted in:

```
Effective Date     FileName
--------------     ---------
25-May-2019
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `Select-Object`'s property hash table and splitting the file path by `\` with the `.Split()` method. The `[-1]` indicates the last item in the split result.

```
$File = '\\webserver\Data_20190626.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $File |
    Select-Object 'Effective Date',@{n='FileName';e={$File.Split('\')[-1]}} -First 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised there's no PSPath or anything.

```
import-csv $file -delimiter ',' | 
select 'Effective Date', @{n='Filename';e={split-path -leaf $file}} -first 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a slightly different way to do things. [*grin*] the `#region >>> create a file to work with` section can be ignored - it is there to provide the data file you didn't provide.

it gets the `EffectiveDate` info by using the way that PoSh can  dot-address one property of an entire collection and then grabbing the 1st item from the resulting array.

it also avoids the often confusing side effects of allowing spaces or other special chacters in property names by using `EffectiveDate` instead of `Effective Date`. if you need to keep using the poorly thot out embedded space, then change that string as needed.

```
$File = "$env:TEMP\Data_20190626.csv"

#region >>> create a file to work with
@'
EffectiveDate
2019-06-25
2006-06-06
2005-05-05
'@ |
    ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath $File -NoTypeInformation
#endregion >>> create a file to work with

$Results = [PSCustomObject]@{
    EffectiveDate = (Import-Csv -LiteralPath $File).EffectiveDate[0]
    FileName = $File
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
EffectiveDate FileName
------------- --------
2019-06-25    C:\Temp\Data_20190626.csv
```